# Angular Class Binding

Tags: angular

I have a code on which I have used class binding. When the button is clicked, the color of the font should change based on the value of textrun. textrun changes between true and false.IF true, it should display text in red color else in green color.

TS File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  textrun=true;
  messageClasses={
    "text-success": !this.textrun,
    "text-error": this.textrun,
    "text-info": !this.textrun

    }

  changetrue(){
  this.textrun=false;
  console.log("done");
}
}
```

HTML File

```
 <h2 [ngClass]="messageClasses">hai</h2>
  <button (click)="changetrue()">click</button>
```

css File

```
.text-success{
  color:green;
}
.text-error{
  color:red;
}
.text-info{
font-style: italic;
}
```

EDIT: I needed the same code to work if I have multiple conditions to be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<h2 [ngClass]="textrun ? 'text-error':'text-success'">hai</h2>
```

or,

```
<h2 [ngClass]="{'text-error': textrun, 'text-success': !textrun }">hai</h2>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmeon2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thank you @Adrita. It sure can be written that way. And it works. I had tried. But I don't understand why the above code doesn't work. Any suggestion on that ?

Comment: @nXn The syntax you were trying was incorrect. I have added another way to do it in the demo

Comment: Thank you. Please update the answer with the answer in Demo so that other can also make use of the info. That worked.Appreciate you Support.

Answer (score 3):

---

**You can use any of the below approach**

---

> Approach 1:

```
<h2 [ngClass]="{'text-error': textrun', 'text-success': !textrun }">hai</h2>
```

> Approach 2:

```
<h2 [ngClass]="textrun ? 'text-error':'text-success'">hai</h2>
```

> Approach 3:

```
<h2 [ngClass]="{true:'text-error',false:'text-success'}[textrun]">hai</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you @Surjeet. But if I have three conditions to be applied. Like I need the font to be italics also, how do I apply class binding?

Comment: Thank you . I got it. Appreciate you Support.

Comment: the last approach  is a ninjs style ‍ 

Comment:  @MuhammedAlbarmavi

Answer (score 2):

**This won't work** since the **messageClasses is loaded only once**, during the class instantiation.

*Change your html to:*

```
<h2 [ngClass]="{
  "text-success text-info": !textrun,
  "text-error": textrun
  }">
  hai
</h2>
<button (click)="changetrue()">click</button>
```

and delete your messageClasses variable from your class

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because you are refering to `this.textrun` on your attributes.

Usually it is not available when the component is initialized:

Try:

```
textrun = true;

messageClasses;

ngOnInit() {
   this.messageClasses = {
    "text-success": !this.textrun,
    "text-error": this.textrun,
    "text-info": !this.textrun
   }
}

onClick() {
  this.textrun = !this.textrun;
  this.messageClasses = {
    "text-success": !this.textrun,
    "text-error": this.textrun,
    "text-info": !this.textrun
  }
}
```

At `ngOnInit()` all attributes should be declared and initialized.

Comment: A brief explanation what was not working would much more helpful instead of 'not working'

Comment: Can you log this after that?

Comment: i made the changes you mentioned and the color isn't changing on button click